# How to redirect the output of custom systemd service to specific console

Tags: systemd

I tried something like

```
[Unit]
Description=top on console

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/top
StandardOutput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/ttyS0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But no luck. there are few other unanswered questions 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48094018/how-to-redirect-script-output-to-the-stdout-of-systemd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above worked for me (systemd version 231) by also adding

```
StandardInput=tty
```

as otherwise `top` refused to run with error *failed tty get*.

Comment: After adding your suggestion - it works fine now. thanks!